# Verify the following identities

Tags: trigonometry

I want to verify the following identities:

$${\sin^3\alpha-\cos^3\alpha\over \sin\alpha -\cos\alpha} = 1 + \sin\alpha \cos\alpha$$

I feel like I need to work on the first member – the second one looks fine. I can't really figure out how to transform the first one. Any hints?

Comment: Factor the numerator - it's the *difference of cubes* formula. Then use the fundamental identity

Comment: The identity is false for alpha = pi/4.

Comment: @djechlin An "identity" in this context certainly means that the functions are identical on their common domain.

Comment: @StevenGubkin really depends, you can't really leave things like that "implied" until mastery is assumed (both college courses and research papers seem to operate on this principle). Given that this problem looks precalc-level seems reasonable to point out the necessary hypothesis.

Comment: @djechlin - you've never seen the statement "the proof of this theorem is beyond the scope of this class"? Or maybe you've never taken a class where the rote exercise of "trig proofs" was taught...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 for your first sentence, isn't that the complete opposite of this situation? for your second sentence, yes, that is the wrong way to teach math, which is why I'm not subscribing to that here.

Comment: The principal is the same - we introduce exercises before fully developing the theory.

Comment: @djechlin I certainly think that pointing out the domain issue is a good thing to do, but I do not think that it invalidates the word "identity" in this situation.  Is $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ not an identity unless we specify that it is over the reals?  I think the assumed context is acceptable if the course deals entirely with real numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:** $u^3-v^3 = (u-v) (u^2+u v+v^2)$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $x \neq y$, $$\dfrac{x^3 - y^3}{x-y} = x^2 + xy + y^2$$

And in your case, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sin^3(a)-\cos^3(a)}{\sin(a)-\cos(a)}=1+\sin(a)\cos(a)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(a)+\cos(a)\sin(a)+\sin^2(a)=1+\sin(a)\cos(a)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(a)+\sin^2(a)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$1=1$$

The left hand side and right hand side are identical

Comment: And assuming $\alpha \neq \pi/4$ or else you multiplied by zero on both sides and claimed it was reversible.

Comment: Going from the first step to the second needs a comment as to what's going on.  Whoever can see what happened wouldn't have needed to ask how to prove the identity in the first place.